# How can I fix an failed install of sklearn for python

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, libraries

I am trying to install sklearn for Python, however whenever I attempt to install something which has files from it as a requirement (such as scikit-neuralnetwork) or I attempt to import sklearn in a Python file, I get errors. In the first scenario I receive the error message below marked A, and for the second I receive an error saying I have no module named sklearn.utils (I've already commented out the correct install check). I've tried reinstalling the libraries but the issue remains the same.

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\tests\data\openml\292\api-v1-json-data-list-data_name-australian-limit-2-data_version-1-status-deactivated.json.gz'

Comment: We need some more contex. How did you install the libraries, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Anaconda. It has all the libraries already downloaded.